# Schema does not exits for a table alis in a stored procedure in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-11

Schema does 'tb' not exists. for tb.DOWName. There  are 3 tables in this query.

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MeetingList ( INT, INT, VARCHAR(25)) 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN   
    SELECT ListID,
    a.DOWID, 
    tb.DOWName 'Day',
    a.aTimeID,
    c.aTime 'Time',
    Town,
    GroupName,
    Information,Location,Type
    FROM list  a
    INNER JOIN dow tb ON a.DOWID = tb.DOWID
    INNER JOIN atime AS c ON a.aTimeID = c.aTimeId
    WHERE (a.DOWID = $1 OR $1 IS NULL)
    AND (a.aTimeID = $2 or $2 IS NULL)
    AND (Town = $3 or $3 IS NULL)
    ORDER BY a.DOWID,a.aTimeID, Town;
END;
$$;
```

Result from query:

```
deig=# CALL MeetingList(1,60,'Ellsworth');
ERROR:  schema "tb" does not exist
LINE 3: tb.DOWName 'Day',
        ^
QUERY:  SELECT ListID,
a.DOWID, 
public.tb.DOWName 'Day',
a.aTimeID,
c.aTime 'Time',
Town,
GroupName,
Information,Location,Type
FROM list  a
INNER JOIN dow tb ON a.DOWID = tb.DOWID
INNER JOIN atime AS c ON a.aTimeID = c.aTimeId
WHERE (a.DOWID = $1 OR $1 IS NULL)
AND (a.aTimeID = $2 or $2 IS NULL)
AND (Town = $3 or $3 IS NULL)
ORDER BY a.DOWID,a.aTimeID, Town
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function meetinglist(integer,integer,character 

varying) line 3 at SQL statement
```

I am running this from psql as user 'bart' using database 'deig'. There are 3 tables:

````
 Schema | Name  | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------+-------+----------
 public | atime | table | bart
 public | dow   | table | bart
 public | list  | table | bart```
````

I have been using this stored procedure in SQL Express but have not succeeded in Postgresql 11.

Answer (score 0):

[Identifiers and aliases](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) should be quoted with `"` instead of `'`

```
SELECT ListID,
       a.DOWID, 
       tb.DOWName AS "Day",
       a.aTimeID,
       c.aTime AS "Time",
 -- ...
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b73b3db78de8be8340dd0509a94f43a6)**

Comment: This changed fixed the issue.